# How many ways to group $5$ into two pairs and a single? I get $30$, but the answer is $15$. How can I tell that I over-counted?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Suppose I have 5 people and I want to group them into two pairs and a single person. How many ways can I do this?

Here is my naive thinking using the binomial coefficient  $$\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{5!}{2^2} = 30$$ However, I've over-counted: I know there should be 15 combinations, but I have 30.

> How can I justify dividing by 2?

Comment: The problem itself is ambiguous. Do you want to group them into "pair 1" and "pair 2" and "single person", or are the two pairs going to be indistinguishable?

Comment: The pairs have to be unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $(AB)(CD)E$ and $(CD)(AB)E$ are actually equal results.

You counted them twice.

So the correct outcome is:$$\frac1{2!}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = 15$$

Comment: That's all the justification that I need? How would I know if I have over counted? Like for example say that I grouped them into a triple and two singles I use my binomial method and get the right number.

Comment: By two singles: $\frac1{2!}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}$ because in that case the singles can be switched. (ABC)(D)(E) and (ABC)(E)(D) are then the same so must be counted as one and not as two.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the single person in $5$ ways. The eldest of the remaining $4$ persons can choose his partner in $3$ ways, and then everything is decided. Makes $5\cdot3=15$ possibilities.